# Adding new Hub sites will not get reflected inside the existing "Associated Hubs" & "Associated Child Hubs"

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, administration, hub-site

We have multiple layers of Hub Sites, and we are using those options to show the related child Hubs and the related Hubs:

[image]

But if we add new Hub sites and link them to existing hub sites >> those new hub sites will not get reflected inside the existing "Associated Hubs" & "Associated Child Hubs" links? so is this a bug?

I waited for around 5 hours for now.

Comment: I've never seen this working either. Seems buggy to me.

Comment: @PaulLucas i am not sure how Microsoft is investing or at-least force us to invest in Hub sites and have this as a bug.. we can have hundreds of sites that are connected with each other using Hubs.. so if we add a new Hub, then we need to manually go through all the sites and update the navigation... looks totally weird !! and certainly it is a BUG.. we never face those issues when using Subsites!!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of hub associations in SharePoint.

As per the Microsoft official documentation [Add links to hub associations to the hub site navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hub-to-hub-association#add-links-to-hub-associations-to-the-hub-site-navigation),

> Navigational links to associated hubs are not automatically updated when there are changes to hub associations in the SharePoint admin center.

I will suggest first add/associate all SharePoint sites to a hub and then try adding  Associated hubs link to the navigation.

Comment: but one advantage of using Hub Site over sub sites its ease to be associated... so new hub sites might get associated, exsisting sites might move to new hub and so one... this will cause all navigation to break

Comment: I agree with your points. You may want to add new feedback/idea on Feedback portal so that Microsoft will implement this in future: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472

Comment: You can also report this behavior by raising support ticket with Microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support

Comment: i posted on microsoft technical community and there mentione that they do not consider it as a bug

Comment: Ok, but they can consider it as a new feature request/feedback to consider it for future releases.